# KeyError 'None' while running poetry lock

Tags: python-poetry

I'm facing the following error while running `poetry lock`:

```
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (9.9s)
  KeyError
  'None'
  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/mixology/version_solver.py:112 in _propagate
      108│             # Iterate in reverse because conflict resolution tends to produce more
      109│             # general incompatibilities as time goes on. If we look at those first,
      110│             # we can derive stronger assignments sooner and more eagerly find
      111│             # conflicts.
    → 112│             for incompatibility in reversed(self._incompatibilities[package]):
      113│                 result = self._propagate_incompatibility(incompatibility)
      114│
      115│                 if result is _conflict:
      116│                     # If the incompatibility is satisfied by the solution, we use
```

Python & Poetry versions:

```
% python --version
Python 3.8.0
% poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide minimal complete and verifiable example?